# how to render a block in template file

Tags: php, drupal

I am fairly new to drupal. I have seen this example on creating a module with blocks. My question is can we send the $content from customblock_block_view to another template file where it can be rendered by adding some extra HTML? If so how?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function customblock_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['list_modules'] = array(
    'info' => t('A listing of all of the enabled modules.'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function customblock_block_view($block_name = '') {
  if ($block_name == 'list_modules') {
    $list = module_list();

    $theme_args = array('items' => $list, 'type' => 'ol');
    $content = theme('item_list', $theme_args);

    $block = array(
      'subject' => t('Enabled Modules'),
      'content' => $content,
    );

    return $block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own template file, you only need register it using [`hook_theme`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7):

```
function customblock_theme() {
    return array(
        'myblock' => array(
        'template' => 'mytpl',
        'variables' => array('variable' => NULL),
        ),
    );
}
```

Next step is create the tpl file; like mytpl.tpl.php in the theme.
Then, call it using [`theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7)

```
theme('myblock',$theme_args);
```

Now, in the template you have `$theme_args` available as `$variable`

Answer (score 1):

Items are rendered using the [`theme($hook, $variables)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) function. Use the [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to find out what to pass as `$hook`. For blocks, it's `block`.

The [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module also tells you whether the item is rendered via a function or a template. In the first case, look for the function `theme_block`. In the second case, look for the file `block.tpl.php`. The documentation of that item tells you, what the `$variables` array should look like.

Construct the `$variables` array and call `theme('block', $variables)`.

Note that in case of a template file, some variables come from a preprocess function as described in the [`theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) documentation. Such variables do not need to be provided by the caller of [`theme($hook, $variables)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7). The relevant preprocess functions should be listed in the template file.

Comment: Can you tell me what are the $variables for the hook 'block' or can you point me to any resource where these parameters are specified?

Comment: I just pointed you to it. Its either in function `theme_block` or in file `block.tpl.php`. It's rare that both exist (only if a contrib module or theme provides a template file for a theme hook that the core renders using a theme function).

Comment: What if i want to  write my custom template for that block?

Comment: Check whether you can use any of the *template suggestions*. This can be done with the [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module. If the template suggestions are not sufficient, you have to implement [hook_preprocess_HOOK()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) to advertise a template suggestion. When you have done that, copy the original template file to the one mentioned by your favorite template suggestion and edit to taste. See [Working with template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/223440) for details.

Comment: For blocks, a template suggestion exists, that allows you to theme a block based on the module that provides the block and the delta of the block within the module. The format of the filename differs among Drupal versions. See [Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) or [Drupal 6 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089642) depending on the version of Drupal that you are using.